# Comparing properties and returning associated siblings

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say I have an arbitrarily large number of objects:

```
obj1 = {
    name: "Fred",
    score: 1
}

obj2 = {
    name: "Steve",
    score: 2
}

obj3 = {
    name: "Billy",
    score: 3
}
```

I'd like to easily compare the `score` properties of each of these objects, and then return the `name` property of the object with the highest score. I'm not completely certain how to easily find the highest value of an arbitrarily large group of numbers, but I'm sure I'll figure it out when the time comes. My real question is how to, after finding the highest score, return the name associated with that score's parent object. (In case of time, my program should return all highest scores.)

Comment: Do you have jQuery available? What should happen if there is more than 1 person with the same highest score?

Comment: _"My real question is how to, after finding the highest score, return the name"_ by returning the `name` property of the object, ie: `obj.name`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Well yes, but I don't necessarily 'know' that objects name. I need to somehow conserve the name of my object after evaluating a huge number of scores.

Comment: Are these objects are in a list/array?

Comment: _"I don't necessarily 'know'"_ well in order to compare the `score` property you have to have access to that object already, just use the same object that you get the `score` from

Comment: @AndreFeijo No jQuery. This is for a class. We haven't learned objects yet, but I've been teaching them to myself. We haven't learned jQuery yet, so if I wanted to apply any new knowledge to class I probably wouldn't be able to use it. In case of a tie, I'd like my function to return all highest persons. I've amended this to my question.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I know. I think the biggest problem is my approach to finding the highest `score`. My current approach is comparing all `scores` and returning the highest one/value of highest one. But I don't know the syntax to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

JSBIN:

http://jsbin.com/cepofigomu/edit?html,js,console,output

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
var data = [
  {
    name: "Fred",
    score: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Steve",
    score: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Billy",
    score: 3
  }
];

var out = data.reduce(function(a, b){
  return a.score > b.score ? a:b ;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: This will only return 1 person in case of a tie.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I only read you did not have jQuery available after I finished writing an example.
You should be able to translate it to pure javascript though.

https://jsfiddle.net/q2x9phf5/

```
var scores = [];

scores.push({
    name: "Fred",
    score: 1
});

scores.push({
    name: "Steve",
    score: 2
});

scores.push({
    name: "Billy",
    score: 3
});

var highestScore = 0;

$.each(scores, function(index, person) {
    highestScore = Math.max(highestScore, person.score);
});

var peopleWithHighestScore = $.grep(scores, function(person) {
    return person.score === highestScore;
});
```